# Temporarily disable all modules for troubleshooting

Tags: plugins

I have a bizarre error going on in the Drupal admin and I want to disable all modules to test if any of them are causing the problem. I have dozens of enabled and dozens of disabled modules. I can go through the process of writing down each module and its status, then manually disabling and re-enabling. However, that seems pretty tedious. Is there a better way to temporarily disable all modules without having to manually remember and tick them on/off?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Attempting to remove a block from a region causes Apache to consume all available memory and, if allowed via `php.ini`:`memory_limit=-1`, to essentially DoS the server.

Comment: Jeff, would the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the machine names of all the enabled modules with the `drush pm-list --type=Module --status=enabled --pipe > enabled.txt` command.

And then iterate through the list do disable:

```
drush -y dis $(<enabled.txt)
```

or enable

```
drush -y en $(<enabled.txt)
```

them.

Comment: Thats a great idea. Though, arent the `en` and `dis` depreciated? I think there is another command involving `pm-install` that would do the trick.